# DeviceSumModuleF32 is broken

Tags: aleagpu

```
let sumModule = (new DeviceSumModuleF32(GPUModuleTarget.Worker(worker))).Create(2e2 |> int)

let t = worker.Malloc([|1.0f;1.0f;1.0f;1.0f;|])
let q = sumModule.Reduce(t.Ptr,4)
```

Without fail, the above code crashes with around 66% probability per run of the last line. I've tried varying the parameters, but it makes no difference. I think the DeviceSumModuleF32 might be broken.

```
let sumModule = (new DeviceReduceModule<float32>(GPUModuleTarget.Worker(worker),<@ (+) @>)).Create(2e9 |> int)

let t = worker.Malloc([|1.0f;1.0f;1.0f;1.0f;|])
let q = sumModule.Reduce(t.Ptr,4)
```

<del>The above works using DeviceReduceModule perfectly fine though.</del>

[See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052024/devicereducemodule-is-broken-as-well)

Edit: I should have written that instead of crashing, it goes into an infinite loop. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug in disposing the GPU module. Here is a workaround, by switch the CUDA context mode to "Threaded", and try to use "use" keyword to maintain the life time of GPU module (GPU module is a result of compilation, so it should be kept alive as long as possible to avoid re-compiling during runtime).

```
// workaround to use threaded cuda context mode
Alea.CUDA.Settings.Instance.Worker.DefaultContextType <- "threaded"
// compile GPU code and keep the module live for a long time
use reduceModule = new DeviceReduceModule<float32>(GPUModuleTarget.Worker(worker),<@ (+) @>)
// now get a reducer from reduce module.
// this reduce object includes some temp memories for algorithm
use reducer = reduceModule.Create(maxReduceNumber)
reducer.Reduce(....)
```

Comment: Nope. Tried switching it to threaded mode and it did not help. I already worked around it though by writing my own reduce module.